# Appropriate intent action to receive a stream of data from a web URI?

Tags: android

I'm trying to receive a stream of data from a web URI of the mimetype text/vcard, so that I can parse it with my vcard parser. My current code is:

```
    Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/our_staff/vcard.php").buildUpon();
    b.appendQueryParameter("upi", items.get(pos));
    Uri uri = b.build();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);                 
    Log.d("URL of staff", uri.toString());
    i.setDataAndType(uri, "text/vcard");
    activity.startActivity(i);
```

However that returns the exception:

```
06-01 06:49:21.021: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/our_staff/vcard.php?upi=kng001 typ=text/vcard }
```

Am I using the wrong type of action for this? Should it not be ACTION_VIEW? Or am I setting the type of data via a wrong method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [URLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).

```
URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```

which you can read into byte array or String and later parse.

Comment: So there is no need for an intent at all in this case?

Comment: No need if you want your parsing work to be done inside your application. On the other hand if you wanted to have some external application to work on the data, then you call it via `Intent`.